# On projection theory for inseparable Hilbert spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, von-neumann-algebras

How can one see that $I$ is an infinite projection in $B(\mathcal{H})$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is an inseparable Hilbert space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\beta$ be a Hilbert basis for $H$. If $\tilde\beta$ is a finite subset of $\beta$ and $f:\beta\rightarrow \beta\setminus\tilde\beta$ is a bijection, then 
$$U:H\rightarrow H,\quad v\mapsto f(v)$$
introduce a partial isometry in $B(H)$ whose initial projection is $I$ and its final projection is $I-P$, where $P$ is a projection on the closed subspace generated by $\tilde\beta$. So $I\sim I-P\neq I$ and that mean $I$ is infinite.

Also, if we choose disjoint subsets $\beta_1,\beta_2$ such that $\beta_1\cup\beta_2=\beta$ and $\beta$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ have same cardinals, the argument like the one above shows that $I$ is properly infinite projection.